# Web3 .send() method promise remains <pending>

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I'm working on a DAPP that connects to a smart contract through Web3 and MetaMask. I'm calling a claim method on the contract as follows:

```
try {
    const claimRes = await batchClaimTokenRewards(tokensArray, weeksArray);
    console.log('claim response: ', claimRes);
    this.getNftDataFromContract();
} catch(error) {
    console.log('claim error: ', error);
}
```

The batchClaimTokenRewards function is imported from another file, here's that function as well:

```
export async function batchClaimTokenRewards(tokensArray:string[], weeksArray:string[]) {
  return distributionContract.methods.batchClaimTokenRewards(tokensArray, [weeksArray]).send({from: web3.utils.toChecksumAddress('<metamask address>')});
}
```

From my understanding, the .send() method called on the contract instance should return a promise, which I should be able to `await`, however, the line where I'm trying to console.log `claimRes` is never reached, even as MetaMask shows the transaction as completed. The `catch()` expression is never reached either. When I log claimRes without using `await` on the promise, I get a `<pending>` promise in the Chrome console that remains in the `<pending>` state and never gets resolved, again, even as MetaMask itself reports the transaction as completed. What can I do to reliably get confirmation of a completed transaction?